# How to download word2vec?

Tags: svn, word2vec

When I'm trying to download Word2vec tool from official [google code page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/), but I got the following:

svn checkout http://word2vec.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://word2vec.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'

svn: E160013: '/svn/trunk' path not found

Comment: The project appears to be abandoned and you can't download that which doesn't exist. Someone forked it and put it on GitHub at https://github.com/dav/word2vec

Comment: For those who end up in this question I suggest: http://vectors.nlpl.eu/repository/#

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can download the original code from here: https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec, whereas I am not sure if there had been further updates to it since the time this snapshot was taken to github.

Or use a "further maintained" implementation of the algorithm, there are quite a few out there, in multiple languages.

Answer (score 11):

For the Google Pre-trained Model :- 
[GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit)

For Google Word2vec Original  Code:- [Link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/)

If you want to make API from your Pre_Trained Model then :- [Link](https://github.com/nishankmahore/word2vec-flask-api)

Answer (score 1):

GoogleCode is closed now

> January 25, 2016 - The project hosting service is closed. You will be
>   able to download a tarball of project source, issues, and wikis.